# Construct PDA that accepts the language $ L = \{ w \in \{ a,b,c\}^*; |w|_c=|w|_a + |w|_b \} $

Tags: computer-science, automata, information-theory

> Problem Construct PDA that accepts the language $ L = \{ w \in \{ a,b,c\}^*; |w|_c=|w|_a + |w|_b \} $

My first idea was this:

- There can be an "a","b" or a "c" at the beginning of a word
- Then we have to differentiate for every new character we read:

  - First letter was a: we need at least one "c" to finish
  - First letter was b: we need at least one "c" to finish
  - First letter was c: we need at least one "a" OR "b" to finish

And here is my PDA:

[image]

Are my thoughts correct? Any idea or suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried simulating your machine with the input `caac`? It looks like there's no matching transition for the second `a`.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Yeah you are all right. That means I have to add case: a,Z;XZ and the same for "b"?

Comment: x @basti: Yes. And then there is no need to distinguish between $q_0$ and $q_1$ anymore.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I have edited my picture. Is it correct now? Thanks for  help!

Comment: x @basti: Yes, that looks okay, assuming that your PDA formalism allows the no-input transition into $q_2$.